# Dealing With Single Quote In Filename

Tags: php

I have this code that finds the flag ( which is a GIF file in "/flags" directory) for a country and displays the flag, but I have a problem with a particular country containing a `'` (single quote or apostrophe) in the filename.

```
$country = "australia";
$flag = (glob("flags/$country.gif"));
```

The flags are named exactly the same as the country name (`$country`), ie: `australia.gif`.

This code works fine except when it encounters the country "Cote d'Ivoire".

```
$country = "cote d'ivoire";
$flag = (glob("flags/$country.gif"));
```

I end up with the following URL for the flag GIF. "/flags/cote%20d"

How do I work around this `'`?

I've tried `htmlspecialchars` and `urlencode` to no avail.

I made a workaround creating a new GIF flag file named "cotedivoire.gif" and added the following code, but this is not ideal. Surely there has to be a better solution.

```
if ($country == "cote d'ivoire") {
    $flag = (glob("flags/cotedivoire.gif"));
}
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Try as `cote d\'ivoire`

Comment: refer this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Comment: @CrazzySkulll `%20` is URL-encoding, not an HTML entity.

Comment: This is the correct behavior. When you put a punctuation character in a URL, it gets encoded as hex. When you process the URL, it will be decoded automatically.

Comment: Not sure if this is a relevant suggestion, but perhaps it would be easier to deal with the country names according to their [ISO 3166 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166). Each country has a specific 2 or 3 character representation. For "Cote d'Ivoire", ie: Ivory Coast, the ISO code is CI. You can be sure that only regular ASCII characters will be used for these codes. It would make sense to save the files with this naming convention.

Comment: @Lix, thanks for the suggestion, a good idea, but I think I'd prefer not renaming all the files. Still not having any luck though, so I might just stick with the `if` workaround. Thanks everyone for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the quotes in your filename string like this:

```
Example: "file'n/ame.jpg";
Solution: "file\'n\/ame.jpg"
```